# Command Button - click and save on desktop of the user (there are many users)

Tags: vba, save, desktop

I have setup the following macro to have the document automatically saved on my desktop with the name in cell D1. However instead of saving in on my desktop it automatically saves under library/documents. It is for multiple users so it should be saved on their desktop when clicking the button.
One comment I deliberately did "\desktop" while otherwise it is just added into the name. It would be great if you could share with me the last piece of the macro.
Many thanks for your help and suggestions.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
  Set objWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  strDesktopPath = objWS.SpecialFolders("\Desktop")
  Dim FileName1 As String
  FileName1 = Range("D1")
  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strDesktopPath & FileName1 & ".xlsm",
  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove "\" from  `strDesktopPath = objWS.SpecialFolders("\Desktop")`

add "\" between `...strDesktopPath` and `& FileName1 & ".xlsm",`

add a continuation characters sequence " `_`" after "`,`"

like follows:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
      Set objWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      strDesktopPath = objWS.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
      Dim FileName1 As String
      FileName1 = Range("D1")
      ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strDesktopPath & "\" & FileName1 & ".xlsm", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    End Sub
```

Comment: @AlmarM, did you get through it?

Comment: Great, it works perfect with your solution. I just checked. Thank you very much for your help :)